# "Access of undefined property..." in for loop declaration? Should not happen... AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, builder

So this is practically straight from the Adobe website. Flash Builder is telling me I am accessing an undefined property when I am clearly not. What is going on?

I am putting a piece of code in to programmatically populate UI elements based on a set number (which will be compared in the for loop to "counter") but I can't even seem to get the for loop to work properly.

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        //var counter:int = new int; 
        for (var counter:int = 0; counter < 5; counter++) 
        { 
            trace(counter); 
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

This is the error I get:

```
1120: Access of undefined property counter. Question1.mxml line 49  Flex Problem
```

No matter if I declare "counter" outside the loop or inside, same error.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm thinking the problem is that I haven't placed the loop inside a function.

Comment: Yep that was the problem.

Comment: Too late =) I saw your comment only after answering...

Comment: Please tag it with `flex` or `mxml`, that makes it easier to understand the environment you work in and categorises the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap this code into function and then call this function whenever you want. You cannot put some code directly in `<fx:Script> <![CDATA[` section, it always must be in functions.